# C# list sub OUs from Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is there a way to get a list of OUs under a parent OU? Right now I can get a list of all OUs but I only want ones that are under the Test OU. This code gets me all existing OUs. How I can change the filter so that it only shows OUs under test?

```
private void oulist_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string defaultNamingContext;

    DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
    defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
    rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + defaultNamingContext);
    //DirectoryEntry domain = new DirectoryEntry((string)"LDAP://" + defaultNamingContext);

    DirectorySearcher ouSearch = new DirectorySearcher(rootDSE, "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)", null, SearchScope.Subtree);

    //MessageBox.Show(rootDSE.Path.ToString());
    SearchResultCollection collectedResult = ouSearch.FindAll();

    try
    {
        foreach (SearchResult temp in collectedResult)
        {
            oulist.Items.Add(temp.Properties["name"][0]);
            DirectoryEntry ou = temp.GetDirectoryEntry();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OU you want to search against can be prefixed against the defaultNamingContext.

So if you wanted to search the root level OU called `Employees`, change the rootDSE line to:

```
rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Employees," + defaultNamingContext);
```

Not all the containers are OU's so Users for example would be `CN=Users,`

Comment: Thank you so much!  I have two more questions.  Is there a way to set that OU via user input?  I would like to have two fields on my GUI one that will specify the root level OU and the other being the combobox that shows the results.

Comment: Forgot my 2nd issue.  
My 2nd issue is the combobox gets filled with the same data every time I select an item from the drop down.  So If my dropdown had Test|A|B|C  and I select A, on the next drop down I have another set of the same values.  How can I prevent this?

Comment: I figured out both.  The first issue i made the following change: rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=" + this.txtboxOU.Text +"," + defaultNamingContext);

2nd issue, I made it a method instead of an event.